# JSON into array of custom objects (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swift4

I have a JSON and i need it to convert it into array of objects.
This is my JSON ( short version of it )

```
[
{
    "categoryID": 5,
    "categoryDescription": "Trips",
    "groupID": 43,
    "groupDescription": "USA",
    "groupImage": "e613c87a-4dab-4929-90cf-2b584fdf0399.jpg",
    "subgroupDescription": "2 days",
    "subgroupPrice": "200"
},
{
   "categoryID": 5,
    "categoryDescription": "Trips",
    "groupID": 43,
    "groupDescription": "USA",
    "groupImage": "e613c87a-4dab-4929-90cf-2b584fdf0399.jpg",
    "subgroupDescription": "5 days",
    "subgroupPrice": "500"
},
{
    "categoryID": 5,
    "categoryDescription": "Trips",
    "groupID": 33,
    "groupDescription": "Mexico",
    "groupImage": "e613c87a-4dab-4929-90cf-2b584fdf0399.jpg",
    "subgroupDescription": "3 days",
    "subgroupPrice": "400"
},
{
    "categoryID": 5,
    "categoryDescription": "Trips",
    "groupID": 33,
    "groupDescription": "Mexico",
    "groupImage": "e613c87a-4dab-4929-90cf-2b584fdf0399.jpg",
    "subgroupDescription": "1 days",
    "subgroupPrice": "150"
},
{
    "categoryID": 3,
    "categoryDescription": "Hotels",
    "groupID": 22,
    "groupDescription": "My Hotel",
    "groupImage": "e613c87a-4dab-4929-90cf-2b584fdf0399.jpg",
    "subgroupDescription": "1 night",
    "subgroupPrice": "50"
},
{
    "categoryID": 3,
    "categoryDescription": "Hotels",
    "groupID": 10,
    "groupDescription": "Your Hotel",
    "groupImage": "e613c87a-4dab-4929-90cf-2b584fdf0399.jpg",
    "subgroupDescription": "2 nights",
    "subgroupPrice": "150"
}]
```

and i need to make a custom objects like this : (How can I create such this object in Swift 4?)

[image]

In JSON we have **categoryID** and **groupID** i need to filter arrays based on them, for example i need to have only one object with categoryID 5. and i need to have only one object with groupID : 43. but i need all subgroups. 
This is the structure of my objects:  ( I don't know if i'm on the right path )

```
struct Categories {
var categoryID: NSNumber
var categoryDescription: String
var groups : [Groups]}

struct Groups {
var geoupID: NSNumber
var geoupDescription: String
var groupImage: String
var subGroups : [Subgroups] }

struct Subgroups {
var subgroupPrice: NSNumber
var subgroupDescription: String }
```

How can I filter it in best way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for how to make the structures, simply use `Decodable` and either name the fields according to what you expect in the JSON, or use `CodingKeys` to specify the names. For example:

```
struct MyStruct: Decodable {
    let categoryID: Int
    let categoryDescription: String
    let groupID: Int
    // …
}
```

Then you can decode your results as `[MyStruct]` using `JSONDecoder`.

Now, the real problem seems to be that you want to have a different structure internally than what you receive as JSON, including constraints like "only one of each `categoryID`". Probably the most straightforward way is to then iterate over the decoded results and copy the contents into different structures.

Instead of arrays (e.g., `var groups: [Groups]`) you could have a dictionary with `groupID` as keys to enforce there being only one of each id, for example:

```
guard let results = try? jsonDecoder.decode([MyStruct].self, from: json) else { return }
var categories = [Int: Category]()
for result in results {
    // fetch existing category or make a new one
    var category = categories[result.categoryID, default: Category(id: result.categoryID, description: result.categoryDescription)]

    // fetch existing group in category or make a new one
    var group = category.groups[result.groupID, default: Group(id: result.groupID, description: result.groupDescription, image: result.groupImage)]

    // append subgroup (always new since there is no id)
    let subgroup = Subgroup(description: result.subgroupDescription, price: result.subgroupPrice)
    group.subgroups.append(subgroup)

    // "save"
    category.groups[result.groupID] = group
    categories[result.categoryID] = category
}
```

Comment: Note that I'm only using `Decodable` as it suffices for what seems to be a throwaway intermediate format, but you can just as well use `Codable` (to add `Encodable`).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tried this before but i have problem with "Subgroups" and "Groups", Do I have to initial Groups in the "for loop" or not ? would you please be more clear about Groups and Subgroups ???

Comment: @Sattar Make `groups` an empty dictionary when you create `Category` and `subgroups` an empty array when you create `Group`, then modify the others. See edited answer (untested code, but the idea should be clear).

Comment: BTW, if you can also affect the JSON side of things, it is quite suboptimal now since it returns duplicate category and group for every subgroup - if you had a similar nested structure in the JSON, the results would be considerably smaller and you could decode them directly into the final structures.

Comment: Thanks, your updated answer is working like a charm, I know this should be done from server side programers and few days ago I have asked them to send me the data in the correct format but they didn't so i decided to do it in the application side, anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Country Json

```
{
      ID = 2;
      Image = "";
      Name = "";
      City =     (
        {
          ID = 74;
          Name = "";
          ParentID = 2;
      },
        {
          ID = 79;
          Image = "";
          Name = Other;
          ParentID = 2;
      }
      );
    },
    {
      ID = 31;
      Image = "";
      Name = "";
      City =     (
        {
          ID = 99;
          Name = "";
          ParentID = 31;
      },
        {
          ID = 100;
          Name = "";
          ParentID = 31;
      });
    }
```

My Class

```
class Country: Codable {

    var id: String?
    var image: String?
    var name: String?
    var cityList: [City]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case id = "ID"
      case image = "Image"
      case name = "Name"
      case city = "City"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

      id = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
      image = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .image)
      name = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
      cityList = try? values.decode([City].self, forKey: .city)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
      var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
      try container.encode(image, forKey: .image)
      try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
      try container.encode(cityList, forKey: .city)
    }

  }

  class City: Codable {

    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var parentId: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case id = "ID"
      case name = "Name"
      case parentId = "ParentID"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      id = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
      name = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
      parentId = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .parentId)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
      var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
      try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
      try container.encode(parentId, forKey: .parentId)
    }

  }
```